# Firefox profile not working selenium webdriver

Tags: firefox, selenium, webdriver, ssl-certificate

I have created a firefox profile as per below steps:

```
   1. firefox.exe -ProfileManager -no-remote
   2. New profile created with name CM
   3. open the new profile and add the certificate
```

Now from my selenium web driver automation script calling this profile

```
    FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
    ProfilesIni allProfiles = new ProfilesIni();
    firefoxProfile = allProfiles.getProfile("CM");

    firefoxProfile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
    firefoxProfile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false);
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
```

but still getting untrusted certificate error.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: did you use the [firefox-profile](https://www.npmjs.org/package/firefox-profile#readme) package?